# how to get album art from mp3 using jsmediatags

Tags: javascript, image, mp3

Hi every one I have a mp3 file like song.mp3 and I want to get its album art and artist name and then want to show in my html webpage . Please tell me how ?

> How to get album from mp3 file and show it in my html img tag 
>   I See this example https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader/blob/master/example/index.html#L46 This work fine for input file But I want to get album from url like song.mp3 that is stored in my site

Please store album image in a variable and then show it in html img tag thanks

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags is a great place to start.

After including jsmediatags. Create a variable (Note that I am using browser example) 
`var jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags;`
Using that variable you can then fetch the ID3 tags of your file as follows;

```
var tags = {};
jsmediatags.read(your_media_file, {
   onSuccess: function(tag) {
      tags = tag;
   }, 
   onError: function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
   }
});
```

The `tags` object has the properties you want and more;

```
{
   artist : 'name of artist',
   album : 'name of album',
   track : 'track number',
   title : 'track title',
   genre : 'track genre',
   picture : {...}, // object with track art details
   .
   .
   .
}
```

You can then generate the album art as follows;

```
var picture = tags.tags.picture; // create reference to track art
var base64String = "";
for (var i = 0; i < picture.data.length; i++) {
    base64String += String.fromCharCode(picture.data[i]);
}
var imageUri = "data:" + picture.format + ";base64," + window.btoa(base64String);
```

Comment: Hi I use your code but i got some trouble please see my code and tell me mistakes and please correct it .It shows undefined

Comment: `picture` was the undefined variable. Create a reference to it before the `for` loop as indicated i.e. `var picture = tags.tags.picture;`

Comment: Where is your-media-file coming from. If I use a local to the html and javascript test1.mp3 file it falls over with: No  suitable file reader found for test1.mp3.