# How to extract cover art from mp3 file path (javascript)

Tags: javascript, audio, metadata

I'm making an audio player and I want to condense the amount of space that the assets are taking up (mp3s and pictures). One way I thought of was putting the images in the mp3's metadata and accessing it from there, as you can then delete the normal image files and it would still work. I figured that getting that metadata from a local file path (like "./Music/SONGNAME.mp3") would be almost the same as getting the metadata from an `<input type="file">`. I have tried many different codes for this, the main gist seeming to be something like this:

```
jsmediatags.read(("./Music/" + song.audio), {
    onSuccess: function(tag) {
      var tags = tag.tags;
      console.log(tags);

      var image = tags.picture;
      if (image) {
        var base64String = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < image.data.length; i++) {
            base64String += String.fromCharCode(image.data[i]);
        }
        var base64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + window.btoa(base64String);
        main.thumbnail.setAttribute('src', base64);
      } else {
        main.thumbnail.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
});
```

("main" is an array of controls and stuff in the player, and song.audio is part of an object in an array of songs. "./Music/" is the folder path to my music)

Anyways, jsmediatags either don't accept file paths or I'm doing something incredibly wrong, because this code pretty much breaks my whole audio player.

If anyone can help, please do!!! (I've been working on this for an unhealthy amount of time...)

Comment: Seems like there are some directions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385981/how-to-get-album-art-from-mp3-using-jsmediatags

Comment: @SanjeevPandey I tried this script as well, but when I'm using a file path, it throws an Error: No suitable file reader found for ./SONGNAME.mp3.
I've also tried using different folder paths like ./Music/SONGNAME.mp3, but it never works

Comment: Me too. I'm getting the feeling that you simply cannot use plain javascript with a browser to access a local file even in your own server directory. I have managed to get tags using id3 (or something) a precursor to jsmediatags, but could see where the album art data or picture was. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Couldn't see...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsmediatags/3.9.5/jsmediatags.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags;
    console.log(jsmediatags)
    // From remote host
jsmediatags.read("https://www.learningcontainer.com/download/sample-mp3-file/?wpdmdl=1676&refresh=62dff4e924c561658844393", {
  onSuccess: function(tag) {
    console.log(tag);
  },
  onError: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the easiest way to implement it on client side

Comment: But then you have to use a url/uri and the file we want to access is on the local server, e.g. ./test1.mp3